# How do I use variables in a select query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery

I have this following select query that uses a scalar function to get full name. I want to eliminate the redundancy by using variable but so far there is no success. My query is

```
select 
 a.Id, 
 a.UserName, 
 getFullName(a.UserName),
 a.CreateTime
from DataTable;
```

I don't want to retrieve 'a.User' two times. I would prefer if I can save a.User in a variable and then pass it to the function hence improving the efficiency.

Currently the work around I came up with is as following

```
select 
 Id, 
 UserName, 
 getFullName(UserName), 
 CreateTime
from (select a.Id, a.UserName, a.CreateTime from DataTable) temp
```

This solves the performance issue but adds the overhead to write same select two time. Any other suggestions would be great.

DataTable looks like this

```
+----+----------+------------+
| Id | UserName | CreateTime |
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 | ab       | 10:00      |
|  2 | cd       | 11:00      |
|  3 | ef       | 12:00      |
+----+----------+------------+
```

Here is the NamesTable used to get the full names

```
+----------+----------+
| UserName | FullName |
+----------+----------+
| ab       | Aa BB    |
| cd       | Cc Dd    |
| ef       | Ee Ff    |
+----------+----------+
```

Here is the function that gets the full name

```
Create function [dbo].[getFullName](@user varchar(150)) returns varchar(500)
as
begin
    declare @Result varchar(500);

  select @Result = FullName from dbo.NamesTable where UserName =  @user;
  return @Result;
end;
```

Comment: The real performance problem here is the existence of a scalar function. They are notoriously poor performers. Then when you stick it in a column it gets worse. Perhaps we can help you create an inline table valued function instead. It will be more flexible and perform better all in fell swoop. We just need some details about what it does and the table structures it utilizes. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Huh?  How is the "work-around" any different from the original query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff In the earlier query the data column is repeatedly selected however in the later query it's a select on the projected data hence faster.

Comment: @fredzyadi Have you _measured_ that it's faster or are you just assuming it is because there seems to be one less operation?  Do you see a significant performance difference between selecting the field in just one expression versus both expressions?

Comment: @DStanley I have examined my full query. One with two operation one with the work around. The first one costs 3 seconds more every time with about 3000 rows to fetch. I have lot of XPath operations. It may be the scalar function together with the column as a parameter that causing the delay. But there's is a performance issue for sure.

Comment: Just sticking to your concern of table access twice ,they don't execute in the way you think.

Comment: It would be useful if you could show us the actual execution plan when you run your query. That would show how costly the function is that is being called. An idea of what that function is doing would also be useful, even if you sanitise the table and field names, you would then get more constructive comments.

Answer (score 4):

You're solving a problem that doesn't exist. You seem to think that

```
select 
 a.Id, 
 a.UserName, 
 getFullName(a.UserName),
 a.CreateTime
from DataTable;
```

Has some relatively expensive process behind it to get `UserName` that is happening twice.  In reality, once the record is located, getting the `UserName` value is an virtually instant process since it will probably be stored in a "variable" by the SQL engine behind the scenes.  You should have little to no performance difference between that query and

```
select 
 a.Id, 
 getFullName(a.UserName),
 a.CreateTime
from DataTable;
```

The scalar function *itself* may have a performance issue, but it's not because you are "pulling" the `UserName` value "twice".

A better method would be to join to the other table:

```
select 
 a.Id, 
 a.UserName, 
 b.FullName,
 a.CreateTime
from DataTable a
LEFT JOIN dbo.NamesTable b
  ON a.UserName = b.UserName
```

Comment: I cannot join it as the table is already joined with another table. Could you please answer the question asked? Is there a way I can store column value in a variable and use it within the select query? Or you think it's not possible.

Comment: No, it's not possible to "store" the column value in a "variable" and reuse it in the function call the way you want it to.  There may be _other_ ways to improve the performance, but you don't provide enough information to give a meaningful suggestion.

Comment: "I cannot join it as the table is already joined with another table."  Not sure what you mean here - you can join to multiple tables.

Comment: I have three tables. My DataTable contains a lot of information with multiple column having usernames (e.g. submittedByUserName, reviewedByUserName and few other). One reason I cannot join Table A with NamesTable is that there's no one username per row. There are maybe 10 different usernames in one row. So I don't know how can I join it as you have suggested.

Comment: You can `JOIN` the same table multiple times as long as you give each one its own alias.

Comment: @TomH As I have mentioned in my prev. comment. The DataTable contains more than one column with usernames. On which column you think I should join it? As far as I can think it's simply not possible to join such a table.

Comment: You have multiple `JOIN`s each naming the same `NamesTable`. The criteria for each `JOIN` is different. Each one would have its own table alias. A good tutorial would cover this... ;)

Comment: @TomH "A good tutorial" that teaches me to join a table 15 time using different aliases for the same table is not a "A good tutorial" :D Are you really suggesting me to join 15 times? How about an example?

Answer (score 3):

As D Stanley says, you're trying to solve some problem that doesn't exist. I would further add that you shouldn't be using the function at all. SQL is meant to perform set-based operations. When you use a function like that you're now making it perform the same function over and over again for every row - a horrible practice. Instead, just `JOIN` in the other table (a set-based operation) and let SQL do what it does best:

```
SELECT
    DT.Id,
    DT.UserName,
    NT.fullname,
    DT.CreateTime
FROM
    DataTable DT
INNER JOIN NamesTable NT ON NT.username = DT.username;
```

Also, `DataTable` and `NamesTable` are terrible names for tables. Of course they're tables, so there's no need to put "table" on the end of the name. Further, of course the first one holds "data", it's a database. Your table names should be descriptive. What **exactly** does `DataTable` hold?

If you're going to be doing SQL development in the future then I strongly suggest that you read several introductory books on the subject and watch as many tutorial videos as you can find.

Comment: These names are just for the example. I am not willing to post my actual query here with real table names and with real table data. I think the example serve the purpose just fine and if you are still not able to answer the question asked then sure you may go ahead and watch as many tutorials as you can find ;)

Comment: The suggestion wasn't based just on the naming conventions. It's obvious from your question that you don't understand some of the basic concepts behind relational databases. That's not intended as a personal insult and I'm sorry if it seems that way. I make much of my money as a consultant fixing code much like you've written because developers think that they can just install SQL and start coding. I'm never going to run out of work, so I'd prefer that more developers avoid those problems altogether.

Comment: How is it "obvious". Okay I'd take your words on apology, moreover I really don't care how much you make as all I care right now is to get the answer to my question. But, I appreciate your concerns for me and the contributions you have made for this community. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Scalar UDF will execute for every row,but not defintely the way you think.below is sample demo and execution plan which proves the same..

```
create table testid
(
id int,
name varchar(20)
)


insert into testid
select n,'abc'
from numbers
where n<=1000000

create index nci_get on dbo.testid(id,name)

select id,name,dbo.getusername(id) from dbo.testid where id>4
```

below is the execution plan for above query
[image]

**Decoding above plan:**
Index seek outputs id,name
Then compute scalar tries to calculate new rows from existing row values.in this case expr1003 which is our function

Index seek cost is 97%,compute scalar cost is 3% and as you might be aware index seek is not an operator which goes to table to get data.so hopefully this clears your question